# pusher can't listen callback events, it throw BroadcastException

Tags: laravel, pusher

I try to test pusher with my application , connection is setup succefuly but pusher can't listen my app events.

I am using laravel 7

broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'ap2',
            'encrypted' => true,
            'useTLS' => true,
        //     'curl_options' => [
        //     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        //     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        // ],
        ],
    ],
```

.env file

```
 APP_URL=http://localhost
 DB_HOST=localhost
 BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
 PUSHER_APP_ID=XXXXX
 PUSHER_APP_KEY=XXXXX
 PUSHER_APP_SECRET=XXXXX
 PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap2
```

EventClass

```
class LikeEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $id;
public $type;

public function __construct($id,$type)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->type = $type;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    //return new PrivateChannel('likeChannel'); //I try both
    return new Channel('likeChannel');
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'LikeEvent';
}
}
```

channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('likeChannel', function () {
return true;
});
```

I try to call event in controller by

```
broadcast(new LikeEvent($reply->id,1))->toOthers();
//broadcast(new LikeEvent($reply->id,1));
//broadcast(new TestEvent("hello pusher"));
//event(new LikeEvent($reply->id,1));
```

it always throw BroadcastException

```
 "message": "",
"exception": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastException",
"file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\rtforum.test\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster.php",
"line": 121,
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by making encryption false

```
'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'ap2',
        'encrypted' => false,
        ]
```